# Convolution of a function with itself using substitution.

Tags: convolution

f(t) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{0<=t<=1} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

I know how to find the convolution when there are 2 functions but how do I find the convolution of a function with itself? The textbook claims that substitution is a method that can be useful but I don't understand how the boundaries would work with substitution.

EDIT: Convolution is from negative infinity to infinity. [convolution function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EktZU.png)

Comment: By convolution of $f$ and $g$, are you taking the integral over the entire real line of $f(x-y)g(y)dy$?

Comment: The convolution is from negative infinity to infinity. I'm not sure how to properly insert the function but I can screenshot the convolution function, [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/c7KwkgD.png)

Comment: The solution is a tent.

Answer (score 1):

$f=1_{[0,1]}$.

$f(t-x) = 1_{[0,1]}(t-x) = 1_{[t-1,t]}(x)$.

$(f * f)(t) = \int f(x) f(t-x) dx = \int 1_{[0,1]}(x) 1_{[t-1,t]}(x) dx = \max(0, t-|t-1|)$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition,
$$
f\star f(t) =:g(t)=  \int_0^t f(s)f(t-s)\,\mathsf ds
= \int_0^t \mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(s)\mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(t-s)\,\mathsf ds.
$$
If $t\in[0,1)$, then $t-1<s<t$ and $0<s<1$ imply $0<s<t$, so we compute
$$
g(t) = \int_0^t \mathsf ds = t.
$$
If $t\in[1,2]$, then similarly we compute 
$$
g(t) = \int_{t-1}^1 \mathsf ds = 2-t.
$$
Hence,
$$g(t) = t\cdot\mathsf 1_{[0,1)}(t) + (2-t)\cdot\mathsf 1_{[1,2]}. $$

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the following experience :

Consider a stripe of paper that has a square hole punched into it. Do a duplicate of this stripe. Slide one on the other in front of a bulb.

The amount of light that flows through the superposition of the two stripes is exactly the result ("tent" function).

(the holes modelize the characteristic function of interval $(0,1)$ and the sliding the convolution).